# Is it Possible to use Enzyme testing with Next js (SSR)?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, next.js, enzyme, react-tsx

It's My first Nextjs project with SSR.

When Integrating Enzyme For Reactjs UI Testing. it could not run due to **"React' refers to a UMD global, but the current file is a module. Consider adding an import instead."**

but it's works when i am using normal Reactjs Component(Functional or Class). Anyone Please give  suggestions.

SandBox Link - https://codesandbox.io/s/currying-moon-gdk09

Full code From GitHub - https://github.com/Rizz13/nextJs-with-Enzyme

***to run testing Use "npm test"***

**pages/Index.tsx**

```
import Head from 'next/head'
import Link from 'next/link'
import { GetStaticProps } from 'next'

export default function Home({
  allPostsData
}: {
  allPostsData: {
    title: string
    id: string
  }[]
}) {
  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <title>Sample Page</title>
      </Head>
      
      <section className="icon-stars">
        <p>[Your Self Introduction]</p>
        <p>
          (This is a sample website - you’ll be building a site like...)
        </p>
      </section>
      <section>
        <h2>Blog</h2>
        <ul>
          {allPostsData.map(({ id, title }) => (
            <li key={id}>
              <Link href="#">
                <a>{title}</a>
              </Link>
              <br />
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </section>
    </>
  )
}

export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps = async () => {
  const allPostsData = [{id: 0, title:"Sample1"}, {id: 1, title:"Sample2"}]
  return {
    props: {
      allPostsData
    }
  }
}
```

**_*tests*_/Index.tsx**

```
import * as React from 'react'
import { expect as expect1 } from 'chai';

import IndexPage from '../pages/index'

import {/*mount,*/ shallow} from 'enzyme' 

const setUp1 = (data) => {
  return shallow(<IndexPage {...data} />);
}
let wrapper;

describe('props Check', () => {

  beforeEach(() => {
      wrapper = setUp1({});
  });

  it('should render an `.icon-stars`', () => {
    expect1(wrapper.find('.icon-stars')).to.have.length(1);
  });

});
```

When I using the Above Code Testing could not run due to below Error.

[image]

Comment: [shenbaga pandian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9289232) [Answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64552257/12695027) to "Check the below sandbox link. I have changed some import statements and shallow method parameters. https://codesandbox.io/s/ancient-hooks-3wnwl?file=/__tests__/index.spec.tsx"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***tests*/Index.tsx**

```
import * as React from 'react'
import { expect as expect1 } from 'chai';

import IndexPage from '../pages/index'

import {/*mount,*/ shallow} from 'enzyme' 

const setUp1 = (data) => {
  return shallow(<IndexPage {...data} />);
}
let wrapper;

describe('props Check', () => {

  beforeEach(() => {
      wrapper = setUp1(allPostsData={[]});
  });

  it('should render an `.icon-stars`', () => {
    expect1(wrapper.find('.icon-stars')).to.have.length(1);
  });

});
```

You have to pass props inside the testing component & use

```
import * as React from 'react'
```

In **pages/Index.tsx** for rendering react components